# "object invoked has disconnected from its clients" Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have seen this asked multiple times but none of the solutions offered have solved my issue- I continue to get this error even though I have used the same code in multiple other applications with no errors.  I have included the code below and hope that someone can spot the issue that I am just failing to see!

```
Sub CreateJobsGraphsPrincipalCategory()
   'Initial variables
   Dim wbnew As Workbook
   Dim wsnew As Worksheet
   Dim Datasheet As Worksheet
   'Dataset variables
   Dim BeneficiaryList(0 To 10000), PrincipalList(0 To 10000), CheckRange As String
   Dim NumberRows, RowNumber As Long
   Dim Isduplicate, intPrincipal, intStatus, intLineItem As Integer
   Dim PrincipalColumn, StatusColumn, LineItemColumn As String
   Dim PrincipalRange, StatusRange, LineItemRange As String
   Dim PrincipalNumber, BeneficiaryNumber As Integer
   'New PivotChart variables
   Dim objPivotcache As PivotCache
   Dim objPivotTable As PivotTable
   Dim bcount As Integer
   Dim ProsperatorArray(1 To 25) As String
   Dim BusinessNameColumn, BeneficiaryName, BeneficiaryNameFind As String
   Dim objPivot As PivotTable, objPivotRange As Range, objChart As Chart
   Dim LastColumnNumber As Double
   'Setup workbooks
   Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook
   Dim SaveToWorkbook As Workbook

  'Stop screen updating and calculating furing processing
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  'Select overall datasheet
   Worksheets("DataforPrincipals").Activate
   Set Datasheet = ActiveSheet

  'Find last column.  Start from column 30 as it will not be less than this
  LastColumnNumber = 30
  LastColumnValue = Datasheet.Cells(1, LastColumnNumber)
  While LastColumnValue <> ""
    LastColumnNumber = LastColumnNumber + 1
    LastColumnValue = Datasheet.Cells(1, LastColumnNumber)
  Wend
  LastColumnNumber = LastColumnNumber - 1
  'LastColumnValue = Datasheet.Cells(1, LastColumnNumber)
  LastColumnValue = Getcolumn(LastColumnNumber)
  'get last row
  LastRowNumber = 1
  LastRowRange = "A" & LastRowNumber
  LastRowValue = Datasheet.Cells(LastRowNumber, 1)
  While LastRowValue <> ""
    LastRowNumber = LastRowNumber + 1
    LastRowRange = "A" & LastRowNumber
    LastRowValue = Datasheet.Cells(LastRowNumber, 1)
  Wend
  LastRowNumber = LastRowNumber - 1
  PivotRange = "A" & "1" & ":" & LastColumnValue & LastRowNumber
  'Creating Pivot cache
  Set objPivotcache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'DataforPrincipals'!" & PivotRange)

  'Create Arrays for Beneficiaries and Principals
  'Get Columns for filtering and checking
  PrincipalColumn = FindDataColumnHeading("Principal")
 ' StatusColumn = FindDataColumnHeading("Status")
  LineItemColumn = FindDataColumnHeading("Line Item")
  BusinessNameColumn = FindDataColumnHeading("Business Name")

  RowNumber = 2
  NumberRows = 0
  CheckRange = BusinessNameColumn & RowNumber
  PrincipalNumber = 1
  BeneficiaryNumber = 1
  While Datasheet.Range(CheckRange) <> ""
    NumberRows = NumberRows + 1
    PrincipalRange = PrincipalColumn & RowNumber
'    StatusRange = StatusColumn & RowNumber
    LineItemRange = LineItemColumn & RowNumber
 '   If Datasheet.Range(StatusRange) = "Active" Then
      If Datasheet.Range(LineItemRange) = "Turnover" Then
         BeneficiaryList(BeneficiaryNumber) = Datasheet.Range(CheckRange)
         BeneficiaryNumber = BeneficiaryNumber + 1
         'Check if principal is in the dataset yet
         If RowNumber = 2 Then
           PrincipalList(PrincipalNumber) = UCase(Trim(Datasheet.Range(PrincipalRange)))
         Else
           PrincipalNumber = PrincipalNumber + 1
           Isduplicate = 0
           For i = 1 To PrincipalNumber
             If PrincipalList(i) = UCase(Trim(Datasheet.Range(PrincipalRange))) Then
               Isduplicate = 1
             End If
           Next i
           If Isduplicate = 0 Then
             PrincipalList(PrincipalNumber) = UCase(Trim(Datasheet.Range(PrincipalRange)))
           Else
             PrincipalNumber = PrincipalNumber - 1
           End If
         End If
       End If
   '  End If

    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
    CheckRange = BusinessNameColumn & RowNumber
  Wend

  Set CurrentWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
'  Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add
  'wbnew = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  CurrentWorkbook.Activate
  For i = 1 To PrincipalNumber
    PrincipalNameFind = PrincipalList(i)
    If PrincipalList(i) <> PrincipalList(i - 1) Then
      If InStr(1, PrincipalList(i), "(") > 0 Then
        PrincipalName = Left(PrincipalList(i), 25) & 0
      Else
        PrincipalName = Left(PrincipalList(i), 25)
      End If
      'Adding new worksheet
      Worksheets("DataforPrincipals").Activate
      Set wsnew = Worksheets.Add
      wsnew.Name = PrincipalName & "JC"
      Worksheets(PrincipalName & "JC").Activate
      'Creating Pivot table
      Set objPivotTable = objPivotcache.CreatePivotTable(wsnew.Range("A1"))
      'set Beneficiary row field
      'Setting Fields
      With objPivotTable
      With .PivotFields("Principal")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .CurrentPage = "ALL"
        .ClearAllFilters
        .CurrentPage = PrincipalNameFind
      End With
     'set data fields (PI TO, TO)
      With .PivotFields("Category")
         .Orientation = xlRowField
      End With
      .AddDataField .PivotFields("PI Total Staff"), "PI Jobs", xlSum
      .AddDataField .PivotFields("Current Total Staff"), "Current Jobs", xlSum
      .AddDataField .PivotFields("Job Growth"), "Job Growth ", xlSum
      With .PivotFields("PI Jobs")
        .NumberFormat = "#"
      End With
      With .PivotFields("Current Jobs")
       .NumberFormat = "#"
      End With
      With .PivotFields("Job Growth ")
       .NumberFormat = "#%"
      End With
      End With
      ' Access the new PivotTable from the sheet's PivotTables collection.
      Set objPivot = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
      ' Add a new chart sheet.
      Set objChart = Charts.Add
      ' Create a Range object that contains
      ' all of the PivotTable data, except the page fields.
      Set objPivotRange = objPivot.TableRange1
      ' Specify the PivotTable data as the chart's source data.
      With objChart
        .ShowAllFieldButtons = False
        .SetSourceData objPivotRange
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .ApplyLayout (5)

        With .ChartTitle
          .Text = " Employment Growth performance per Category"
        End With
        .SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = False
        .SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = False
        .SeriesCollection(3).HasDataLabels = False

        .Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = False
        .DataTable.Select
      End With

      If InStr(1, PrincipalList(i), "(") > 0 Then
        PrincipalName = Left(PrincipalList(i), 25) & 0
      Else
        PrincipalName = Left(PrincipalList(i), 25)
      End If
      ActiveSheet.Name = PrincipalName & " JCG"
      If Sheetslist = "" Then
        Sheetslist = PrincipalName & " JCG"
      Else
        Sheetslist = Sheetslist & ", " & PrincipalName & " JOBS"
      End If
    End If
  Next i

  'Copy to new file
  Set CurrentWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
  DirectoryName = Sheets("Run Automated").Range("B1")
  For i = 1 To PrincipalNumber
    If PrincipalList(i) <> PrincipalList(i - 1) Then
      With Worksheets("Run Automated")
         NameFileInitial = .Range("B2") & " " & PrincipalList(i) & ".xlsm"
      End With
      If InStr(1, PrincipalList(i), "(") > 0 Then
        PrincipalName = Left(PrincipalList(i), 25) & 0
      Else
        PrincipalName = Left(PrincipalList(i), 25)
      End If
    'Set sheets to save
      sheet1save = PrincipalName & " TC"
      sheet2save = PrincipalName & " TOC"
      sheet7save = PrincipalName & "JC"
      sheet8save = PrincipalName & " JCG"
      Set CurrentWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
      Namefile = DirectoryName & "\" & NameFileInitial
      Workbooks.Open Namefile
      Set SaveToWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      CurrentWorkbook.Sheets(Array(sheet1save, sheet2save, sheet7save, sheet8save)).Move Before:=SaveToWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      CurrentWorkbook.Activate
    End If
  Next i
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Which *specific* line?  `Set SaveToWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook`? I'd take a look at [Avoid using SELECT or ACTIVATE](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201610201433279460264) to begin with.

Comment: CurrentWorkbook.Sheets(Array(sheet1save, sheet2save, sheet7save, sheet8save)).Move Before:=SaveToWorkbook.Sheets(1)    Is the line causing the error